# How doI indicate that there are additional or hidden tabs in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I have a TabLayout with many Tabs. One can scroll left or right. How can I get an indicator showing that there are more tabs so users can notice and scroll? Cannot find anything in the documentation.

Comment: Do you mean a `Tabs` container or do you work with the `TabLayout` directly? What sort of indicator do you want? Normally you can just add a button or a fade out effect as a layer on top of the layout.

Comment: A Tabs container. Something like an arrow or ellipsis.

Comment: You can style the `TabsContainer` to include that as an image. You can set a BgPainter to its style so it will draw that dynamically

Comment: Wow. Above my skill level. Any example code?

Comment: Sorry I don't have something off the cuff for doing that right now. Styling should be simple but it isn't dynamic